# SIGSEGV while requiring module in meteor js

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

I have been using Node's Edge module to call c# methods in a dll. I have successfully been able to call c# methods using Edge in my NodeJS application.

Since our company is using MeteorJS, and it only supports Npm modules inside Meteor packages (or through meteorhacks:npm meteor package), I have created a local meteor package and used Meteor's Npm.depends and Npm.require to get the edge npm module. But when I run the project I get the following stack trace and the meteor application is restarting. Can anyone suggest me a way to workaround this issue.

I have tested other npm modules just to make sure that it is not the problem of accessing npm modules itself.

Stack Trace:

```
W20150127-16:12:23.928(8)? (STDERR)           
W20150127-16:12:23.930(8)? (STDERR) Native stacktrace:
W20150127-16:12:23.930(8)? (STDERR) 
W20150127-16:12:23.930(8)? (STDERR) 
W20150127-16:12:23.930(8)? (STDERR) Debug info from gdb:
W20150127-16:12:23.930(8)? (STDERR) 
W20150127-16:12:24.905(8)? (STDERR) (lldb) command source -s 0 '/tmp/mono-gdb-commands.ZfFf2s'
W20150127-16:12:24.905(8)? (STDERR) Executing commands in '/private/tmp/mono-gdb-commands.ZfFf2s'.
W20150127-16:12:24.905(8)? (STDERR) (lldb) process attach --pid 5763
W20150127-16:12:27.640(8)? (STDERR) Process 5763 stopped
W20150127-16:12:27.640(8)? (STDERR) Executable module set to "/Users/kishorj/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.40.1ea2549++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/bin/node".
W20150127-16:12:27.640(8)? (STDERR) Architecture set to: x86_64-apple-macosx.
W20150127-16:12:27.640(8)? (STDERR) (lldb) thread list
W20150127-16:12:27.677(8)? (STDERR) Process 5763 stopped
W20150127-16:12:27.677(8)? (STDERR) * thread #1: tid = 0x1b93f, 0x00007fff932b28fe libsystem_kernel.dylib`__wait4 + 10, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = signal SIGSTOP
W20150127-16:12:27.677(8)? (STDERR)   thread #2: tid = 0x1b940, 0x00007fff932ad52e libsystem_kernel.dylib`mach_msg_trap + 10
W20150127-16:12:27.677(8)? (STDERR)   thread #3: tid = 0x1b941, 0x00007fff932b322e libsystem_kernel.dylib`kevent64 + 10, queue = 'com.apple.libdispatch-manager'
W20150127-16:12:27.677(8)? (STDERR)   thread #4: tid = 0x1b942, 0x00007fff932ad56a libsystem_kernel.dylib`semaphore_wait_trap + 10, name = 'SamplerThread'
W20150127-16:12:27.677(8)? (STDERR)   thread #5: tid = 0x1b945, 0x00007fff932b2132 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__psynch_cvwait + 10
W20150127-16:12:27.678(8)? (STDERR)   thread #6: tid = 0x1b946, 0x00007fff932b2132 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__psynch_cvwait + 10
W20150127-16:12:27.678(8)? (STDERR)   thread #7: tid = 0x1b947, 0x00007fff932b2132 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__psynch_cvwait + 10
W20150127-16:12:27.678(8)? (STDERR)   thread #8: tid = 0x1b948, 0x00007fff932b2132 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__psynch_cvwait + 10
W20150127-16:12:27.678(8)? (STDERR) (lldb) thread backtrace all
W20150127-16:12:27.695(8)? (STDERR) * thread #1: tid = 0x1b93f, 0x00007fff932b28fe libsystem_kernel.dylib`__wait4 + 10, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = signal SIGSTOP
W20150127-16:12:27.695(8)? (STDERR)   * frame #0: 0x00007fff932b28fe libsystem_kernel.dylib`__wait4 + 10
W20150127-16:12:27.695(8)? (STDERR)     frame #1: 0x000000010459e5d9 libmonoboehm-2.0.1.dylib`mono_handle_native_sigsegv + 421
W20150127-16:12:27.695(8)? (STDERR)     frame #2: 0x000000010450deb3 libmonoboehm-2.0.1.dylib`mono_sigsegv_signal_handler + 194
W20150127-16:12:27.696(8)? (STDERR)     frame #3: 0x00007fff8d7c8f1a libsystem_platform.dylib`_sigtramp + 26
W20150127-16:12:27.696(8)? (STDERR)     frame #4: 0x00000001046ec8ae libmonoboehm-2.0.1.dylib`GC_push_all_eager + 64
W20150127-16:12:27.696(8)? (STDERR)     frame #5: 0x00000001046f2b1f libmonoboehm-2.0.1.dylib`GC_push_all_stacks + 409
W20150127-16:12:27.696(8)? (STDERR)     frame #6: 0x00000001046eb6af libmonoboehm-2.0.1.dylib`GC_mark_some + 417
W20150127-16:12:27.696(8)? (STDERR)     frame #7: 0x00000001046e561e libmonoboehm-2.0.1.dylib`GC_stopped_mark + 230
W20150127-16:12:27.697(8)? (STDERR)     frame #8: 0x00000001046e546a libmonoboehm-2.0.1.dylib`GC_try_to_collect_inner + 336
W20150127-16:12:27.697(8)? (STDERR)     frame #9: 0x00000001046edebe libmonoboehm-2.0.1.dylib`GC_init_inner + 755
W20150127-16:12:27.697(8)? (STDERR)     frame #10: 0x00000001046edbb2 libmonoboehm-2.0.1.dylib`GC_init + 30
W20150127-16:12:27.697(8)? (STDERR)     frame #11: 0x00000001046b0b58 libmonoboehm-2.0.1.dylib`mono_gc_base_init + 72
W20150127-16:12:27.697(8)? (STDERR)     frame #12: 0x000000010468954a libmonoboehm-2.0.1.dylib`mono_init_internal + 152
W20150127-16:12:27.697(8)? (STDERR)     frame #13: 0x000000010450e92c libmonoboehm-2.0.1.dylib`mini_init + 1651
W20150127-16:12:27.697(8)? (STDERR)     frame #14: 0x0000000102fa7699 edge.node`MonoEmbedding::Initialize() + 167
W20150127-16:12:27.697(8)? (STDERR)     frame #15: 0x0000000102fa750c edge.node`init(v8::Handle) + 41
W20150127-16:12:27.698(8)? (STDERR)     frame #16: 0x00000001003cbafe node`node::DLOpen(v8::Arguments const&) + 669
W20150127-16:12:27.698(8)? (STDERR)     frame #17: 0x000000010014f58b node`v8::internal::Builtin_HandleApiCall(v8::internal::(anonymous namespace)::BuiltinArguments, v8::internal::Isolate*) + 459
W20150127-16:12:27.698(8)? (STDERR)     frame #18: 0x00000dfbe500618e
W20150127-16:12:27.698(8)? (STDERR)     frame #19: 0x00000dfbe5059e76
W20150127-16:12:27.698(8)? (STDERR)     frame #20: 0x00000dfbe5049287
W20150127-16:12:27.698(8)? (STDERR)     frame #21: 0x00000dfbe500a96e
W20150127-16:12:27.698(8)? (STDERR)     frame #22: 0x00000dfbe5325c28
W20150127-16:12:27.698(8)? (STDERR)     frame #23: 0x00000dfbe53f48f7
W20150127-16:12:27.699(8)? (STDERR)     frame #24: 0x00000dfbe56172c0
W20150127-16:12:27.699(8)? (STDERR)     frame #25: 0x00000dfbe502851e
W20150127-16:12:27.699(8)? (STDERR)     frame #26: 0x00000dfbe5062ff0
W20150127-16:12:27.699(8)? (STDERR)     frame #27: 0x00000dfbe505dd85
W20150127-16:12:27.699(8)? (STDERR)     frame #28: 0x00000dfbe5059e76
W20150127-16:12:27.699(8)? (STDERR)     frame #29: 0x00000dfbe5049287
W20150127-16:12:27.699(8)? (STDERR)     frame #30: 0x00000dfbe500a96e
W20150127-16:12:27.699(8)? (STDERR)     frame #31: 0x00000dfbe5325c28
W20150127-16:12:27.700(8)? (STDERR)     frame #32: 0x00000dfbe5063949
W20150127-16:12:27.700(8)? (STDERR)     frame #33: 0x00000dfbe50ad9aa
W20150127-16:12:27.700(8)? (STDERR)     frame #34: 0x00000dfbe56168ee
W20150127-16:12:27.700(8)? (STDERR)     frame #35: 0x00000dfbe5616604
W20150127-16:12:27.700(8)? (STDERR)     frame #36: 0x00000dfbe56166fe
W20150127-16:12:27.700(8)? (STDERR)     frame #37: 0x00000dfbe50a475f
W20150127-16:12:27.700(8)? (STDERR)     frame #38: 0x00000dfbe500a96e
W20150127-16:12:27.701(8)? (STDERR)     frame #39: 0x00000dfbe505412a
W20150127-16:12:27.701(8)? (STDERR)     frame #40: 0x00000dfbe5075547
W20150127-16:12:27.701(8)? (STDERR)     frame #41: 0x00000dfbe500a96e
W20150127-16:12:27.701(8)? (STDERR)     frame #42: 0x00000dfbe50a3d7d
W20150127-16:12:27.701(8)? (STDERR)     frame #43: 0x00000dfbe50245e7
W20150127-16:12:27.701(8)? (STDERR)     frame #44: 0x00000dfbe50118b7
W20150127-16:12:27.701(8)? (STDERR)     frame #45: 0x00000001001801fd node`v8::internal::Invoke(bool, v8::internal::Handle, v8::internal::Handle, int, v8::internal::Handle*, bool*) + 445
W20150127-16:12:27.702(8)? (STDERR)     frame #46: 0x000000010012780e node`v8::Function::Call(v8::Handle, int, v8::Handle*) + 462
W20150127-16:12:27.702(8)? (STDERR)     frame #47: 0x0000000100bf3334 fibers.node`Fiber::RunFiber(void**) + 276
W20150127-16:12:27.702(8)? (STDERR)     frame #48: 0x0000000100bf3c7d fibers.node`Coroutine::trampoline(void*) + 29
W20150127-16:12:27.702(8)? (STDERR)     frame #49: 0x0000000100bf4b52 fibers.node`coro_init + 66
W20150127-16:12:27.702(8)? (STDERR)     frame #50: 0x0000000100bf4915 fibers.node`trampoline + 37
W20150127-16:12:27.702(8)? (STDERR)     frame #51: 0x00007fff8d7c8f2d libsystem_platform.dylib`_sigtramp + 45
W20150127-16:12:27.702(8)? (STDERR)     frame #52: 0x00007fff932b2727 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__sigsuspend + 11
W20150127-16:12:27.702(8)? (STDERR)     frame #53: 0x00007fff92b34289 libsystem_malloc.dylib`szone_malloc_should_clear + 1142
W20150127-16:12:27.703(8)? (STDERR) 
W20150127-16:12:27.703(8)? (STDERR)   thread #2: tid = 0x1b940, 0x00007fff932ad52e libsystem_kernel.dylib`mach_msg_trap + 10
W20150127-16:12:27.703(8)? (STDERR)     frame #0: 0x00007fff932ad52e libsystem_kernel.dylib`mach_msg_trap + 10
W20150127-16:12:27.703(8)? (STDERR)     frame #1: 0x00007fff932ac69f libsystem_kernel.dylib`mach_msg + 55
W20150127-16:12:27.703(8)? (STDERR)     frame #2: 0x00007fff94161b14 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 212
W20150127-16:12:27.703(8)? (STDERR)     frame #3: 0x00007fff94160fdb CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 1371
W20150127-16:12:27.703(8)? (STDERR)     frame #4: 0x00007fff94160838 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 296
W20150127-16:12:27.703(8)? (STDERR)     frame #5: 0x00007fff94216ed1 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRun + 97
W20150127-16:12:27.704(8)? (STDERR)     frame #6: 0x00000001004205a4 node`uv__cf_loop_runner + 67
W20150127-16:12:27.704(8)? (STDERR)     frame #7: 0x0000000100414a82 node`uv__thread_start + 25
W20150127-16:12:27.704(8)? (STDERR)     frame #8: 0x00007fff8ec1f2fc libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_body + 131
W20150127-16:12:27.704(8)? (STDERR)     frame #9: 0x00007fff8ec1f279 libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_start + 176
W20150127-16:12:27.704(8)? (STDERR)     frame #10: 0x00007fff8ec1d4b1 libsystem_pthread.dylib`thread_start + 13
W20150127-16:12:27.704(8)? (STDERR) 
W20150127-16:12:27.704(8)? (STDERR)   thread #3: tid = 0x1b941, 0x00007fff932b322e libsystem_kernel.dylib`kevent64 + 10, queue = 'com.apple.libdispatch-manager'
W20150127-16:12:27.704(8)? (STDERR)     frame #0: 0x00007fff932b322e libsystem_kernel.dylib`kevent64 + 10
W20150127-16:12:27.705(8)? (STDERR)     frame #1: 0x00007fff9337bd91 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_mgr_invoke + 247
W20150127-16:12:27.705(8)? (STDERR)     frame #2: 0x00007fff9337ba6a libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_mgr_thread + 52
W20150127-16:12:27.705(8)? (STDERR) 
W20150127-16:12:27.705(8)? (STDERR)   thread #4: tid = 0x1b942, 0x00007fff932ad56a libsystem_kernel.dylib`semaphore_wait_trap + 10, name = 'SamplerThread'
W20150127-16:12:27.705(8)? (STDERR)     frame #0: 0x00007fff932ad56a libsystem_kernel.dylib`semaphore_wait_trap + 10
W20150127-16:12:27.706(8)? (STDERR)     frame #1: 0x00000001003c4348 node`v8::internal::MacOSSemaphore::Wait() + 24
W20150127-16:12:27.706(8)? (STDERR)     frame #2: 0x00000001002d7ba7 node`v8::internal::RuntimeProfilerRateLimiter::SuspendIfNecessary() + 119
W20150127-16:12:27.706(8)? (STDERR)     frame #3: 0x00000001003c43f8 node`v8::internal::SamplerThread::Run() + 56
W20150127-16:12:27.706(8)? (STDERR)     frame #4: 0x00000001003c3c1c node`v8::internal::ThreadEntry(void*) + 60
W20150127-16:12:27.706(8)? (STDERR)     frame #5: 0x00007fff8ec1f2fc libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_body + 131
W20150127-16:12:27.706(8)? (STDERR)     frame #6: 0x00007fff8ec1f279 libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_start + 176
W20150127-16:12:27.706(8)? (STDERR)     frame #7: 0x00007fff8ec1d4b1 libsystem_pthread.dylib`thread_start + 13
W20150127-16:12:27.706(8)? (STDERR) 
W20150127-16:12:27.707(8)? (STDERR)   thread #5: tid = 0x1b945, 0x00007fff932b2132 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__psynch_cvwait + 10
W20150127-16:12:27.708(8)? (STDERR)     frame #0: 0x00007fff932b2132 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__psynch_cvwait + 10
W20150127-16:12:27.708(8)? (STDERR)     frame #1: 0x00007fff8ec1fea0 libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_cond_wait + 693
W20150127-16:12:27.708(8)? (STDERR)     frame #2: 0x000000010041dd76 node`uv_cond_wait + 9
W20150127-16:12:27.708(8)? (STDERR)     frame #3: 0x000000010041e573 node`worker + 208
W20150127-16:12:27.708(8)? (STDERR)     frame #4: 0x0000000100414a82 node`uv__thread_start + 25
W20150127-16:12:27.709(8)? (STDERR)     frame #5: 0x00007fff8ec1f2fc libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_body + 131
W20150127-16:12:27.710(8)? (STDERR)     frame #6: 0x00007fff8ec1f279 libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_start + 176
W20150127-16:12:27.711(8)? (STDERR)     frame #7: 0x00007fff8ec1d4b1 libsystem_pthread.dylib`thread_start + 13
W20150127-16:12:27.711(8)? (STDERR) 
W20150127-16:12:27.712(8)? (STDERR)   thread #6: tid = 0x1b946, 0x00007fff932b2132 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__psynch_cvwait + 10
W20150127-16:12:27.712(8)? (STDERR)     frame #0: 0x00007fff932b2132 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__psynch_cvwait + 10
W20150127-16:12:27.712(8)? (STDERR)     frame #1: 0x00007fff8ec1fea0 libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_cond_wait + 693
W20150127-16:12:27.712(8)? (STDERR)     frame #2: 0x000000010041dd76 node`uv_cond_wait + 9
W20150127-16:12:27.713(8)? (STDERR)     frame #3: 0x000000010041e573 node`worker + 208
W20150127-16:12:27.713(8)? (STDERR)     frame #4: 0x0000000100414a82 node`uv__thread_start + 25
W20150127-16:12:27.713(8)? (STDERR)     frame #5: 0x00007fff8ec1f2fc libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_body + 131
W20150127-16:12:27.713(8)? (STDERR)     frame #6: 0x00007fff8ec1f279 libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_start + 176
W20150127-16:12:27.713(8)? (STDERR)     frame #7: 0x00007fff8ec1d4b1 libsystem_pthread.dylib`thread_start + 13
W20150127-16:12:27.714(8)? (STDERR) 
W20150127-16:12:27.714(8)? (STDERR)   thread #7: tid = 0x1b947, 0x00007fff932b2132 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__psynch_cvwait + 10
W20150127-16:12:27.714(8)? (STDERR)     frame #0: 0x00007fff932b2132 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__psynch_cvwait + 10
W20150127-16:12:27.723(8)? (STDERR)     frame #1: 0x00007fff8ec1fea0 libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_cond_wait + 693
W20150127-16:12:27.724(8)? (STDERR)     frame #2: 0x000000010041dd76 node`uv_cond_wait + 9
W20150127-16:12:27.724(8)? (STDERR)     frame #3: 0x000000010041e573 node`worker + 208
W20150127-16:12:27.726(8)? (STDERR)     frame #4: 0x0000000100414a82 node`uv__thread_start + 25
W20150127-16:12:27.726(8)? (STDERR)     frame #5: 0x00007fff8ec1f2fc libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_body + 131
W20150127-16:12:27.726(8)? (STDERR)     frame #6: 0x00007fff8ec1f279 libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_start + 176
W20150127-16:12:27.726(8)? (STDERR)     frame #7: 0x00007fff8ec1d4b1 libsystem_pthread.dylib`thread_start + 13
W20150127-16:12:27.726(8)? (STDERR) 
W20150127-16:12:27.726(8)? (STDERR)   thread #8: tid = 0x1b948, 0x00007fff932b2132 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__psynch_cvwait + 10
W20150127-16:12:27.727(8)? (STDERR)     frame #0: 0x00007fff932b2132 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__psynch_cvwait + 10
W20150127-16:12:27.727(8)? (STDERR)     frame #1: 0x00007fff8ec1fea0 libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_cond_wait + 693
W20150127-16:12:27.727(8)? (STDERR)     frame #2: 0x000000010041dd76 node`uv_cond_wait + 9
W20150127-16:12:27.727(8)? (STDERR)     frame #3: 0x000000010041e573 node`worker + 208
W20150127-16:12:27.727(8)? (STDERR)     frame #4: 0x0000000100414a82 node`uv__thread_start + 25
W20150127-16:12:27.727(8)? (STDERR)     frame #5: 0x00007fff8ec1f2fc libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_body + 131
W20150127-16:12:27.728(8)? (STDERR)     frame #6: 0x00007fff8ec1f279 libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_start + 176
W20150127-16:12:27.728(8)? (STDERR)     frame #7: 0x00007fff8ec1d4b1 libsystem_pthread.dylib`thread_start + 13
W20150127-16:12:27.728(8)? (STDERR) (lldb) detach
W20150127-16:12:27.728(8)? (STDERR) 
W20150127-16:12:27.728(8)? (STDERR) =================================================================
W20150127-16:12:27.728(8)? (STDERR) Got a SIGSEGV while executing native code. This usually indicates
W20150127-16:12:27.729(8)? (STDERR) a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries 
W20150127-16:12:27.729(8)? (STDERR) used by your application.
W20150127-16:12:27.729(8)? (STDERR) =================================================================
W20150127-16:12:27.729(8)? (STDERR) 
W20150127-16:12:27.729(8)? (STDERR) Process 5763 detached
W20150127-16:12:27.729(8)? (STDERR) (lldb) quit
W20150127-16:12:27.729(8)? (STDERR) (lldb) XR1L
```

Comment: I'd test with-out meteor, on node `v0.10.33` (version packaged with meteor), and also try to have `node-fibers` installed at the same time as `edge` - as they both hook in to low-level node api's, and they may conflict.